# Pull request時に静的なファイルや自動生成されたファイルをGitHub上のdiffに表示しないようにするには？

Tags: git, github

GitHubでPull requestを作成して他のメンバーにコードレビューしてもらう際、静的なファイルや自動生成されたファイルを表示させないようにする方法はないでしょうか？

外部の有料CSSテンプレートなどを導入すると、自分で書いたわけではないCSS、JS、画像等が大量にpull requestに含まれる場合があります。  
こうしたファイルは特別な理由がない限りコードレビューしてもらう必要はありません。   
それよりも、自分自身が書いたコードを重点的にレビューしてもらうことの方が重要です。

しかし、普通にpull requestを作成すると、自分が書いたコードも外部から持ってきたファイルもすべてpull requestのdiffに含まれるため、第三者が見たときに非常に効率が悪くなります。    
また、数が多すぎるとGitHubが白旗を揚げる場合もあります。（下記イメージ参照）

[image: GitHubが白旗を揚げる例]

こうした問題を避けるために、特定のディレクトリ以下は（diff上では）無視するとか、別々のpull requestにするとか、何かしらの回避策があれば教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

多少煩雑ではありますが、Pull requestのコミットを

1. 静的ファイル、自動生成ファイルの追加
2. レビューして欲しい変更

の複数段階に分けて、レビューアにはPull requestの番号と2.のコミットへのリンクを提示する、という方法ではいかがでしょうか。
（というようなblogかQiitaの記事を見た覚えがあるのですが、所在不明です……）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。そのQiita記事はもしかすると[こちら](http://qiita.com/meganemura/items/8a034e2065b299135c87)でしょうか？僕もこの記事は参考にしたんですが、あくまでコミットレベルなんですよね。pull reqではなく。可能であれば回答のような手順でコミット＆先にマージするんですが、毎回きれいに線引きができるわけでもないので後からでも何とかできる方法がないかなと模索している次第です。

Comment: はい、まさにその記事です。
GitHubでは一つのPull requestに含まれるコミットは複数リンク付きで表示されますし、コミットコメントで「レビュー不要」を明示する、などの運用ルールで回避するのが現実的なラインという気がします。
単一PRに必要なコミットが全部含まれていれば、マージプロセスも楽ですし。

Answer (score 1):

差分を出したくない静的ファイルのみを commit した branch (A) とレビューしたいコードを commit した branch (B) を分け、GitHub 上で PullRequest を作る時に、base を A、compare を B に指定していました。

具体的な手順としては、以下のような感じです。
git-flow モデルで運用している前提とします。

1. git checkout develop
2. git checkout -b feature/A
3. git add staticfiles && git commit -m 'commit static files'
4. git push origin feature/A
5. git checkout -b feature/B
6. git add pleasereview && git commit -m 'please review this commit'
7. git push origin feature/B
8. GitHub 上で以下のように指定して PullRequest を作る。
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

develop へのマージ時は以下の点に、気をつけなければなりません。
必ず、feature/B を feature/A にマージした後、feature/A を develop にマージするということです。

diff が大量に出て GitHub 上でのレビュー運用がうまくいかないという点を解消するには、個人的には今のところベストプラクティスかなと考えています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。こちらもやはりコミットする順番が重要になってきますね。（先に静的ファイルをコミット、それから機能的なコードをコミット）やっぱり同じブランチでごっちゃにコミットしてしまったらアウト、っていうことなのかな～と思ってきました。

Answer (score 1):

ジャストアイデアで実際には試していませんが、以下のような手順だとうまくいくかもしれません。

1. 一通りコードが出来上がった時点で静的ファイルが含まれるディレクトリを削除してコミット
2. Pull request作成、コードレビュー依頼
3. 必要に応じてコードを修正、コミット、push
4. コードレビューが終わったら、1のコミットをrevert＆GitHubにpush
5. Pull requestをマージ

懸念等があればコメントをください。

Comment: そのコミットを実際に動かしてテストしたい場合に静的ファイルを戻す手間があること、4のrevertに問題がないかどうか再度チェックすべきこと、多少履歴がややこしくなること、あたりが気になりますが、そういうアプローチもありかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

なぜ日本語ではgithub linguistの情報が少ないのか

というわけで記事書きました。おそらく質問者さんがやりたいことが出来るかと思います。

[GithubのPullRequestで、自動生成されたファイルなどのdiffを非表示にする - Qiita](https://qiita.com/takezoux2/items/00a60d524cc0e787e6c3)

Comment: 「詳しくはリンク先に書いてあります」という形式ですと、将来何らかの理由でリンク先が消えた場合にせっかくの回答が意味を成さなくなってしまうので、要点をこちらの投稿にも含めてもらうとより良い回答になると思います。